# VBA Vlookup function

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I keep getting this error saying object doesn't support property or method when I run this bit of my code.

Any ideas how to get it to work?

```
If ActiveCell.Value <> WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), Workbooks("Log.xls").Worksheets("Log").Range("A:B"), 2, False) Then
    [f2].Value = vvvv

End If
```

Comment: No repro - the error message isn't "Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"?

Comment: Where is the code? (i.e. is it in a module, class, worksheet...)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
If ActiveCell.Value <> Application.VLookup(CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)), Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B"), 2, False) Then
        [f2].Value = vvvv

End If
```

More details: You must control the type of the lookup value in VLOOKUP function

Comment: This will still error when no match is found, one cannot compare an error to a value.

Comment: True, but thats error handling. Not, getting the expression to evaluate TRUE which is what he's trying to do.

Comment: but the error he is getting is because the value was not found and that would return an error.  This does not fix the issue.

Comment: "You must control the type of the lookup value in VLOOKUP function" - this is not correct.